# Why is the inverse of this function negative?

Tags: functions, inverse

$$f(x) = 2x^2 - 12x + 7 \,\,\,,x\le3$$
$$f^{-1}(x) = - \sqrt{(x+11)/2} + 3$$

why is the square root negative? how to know when it's supposed to be negative or positive? Could you please explain the reasoning and logic?

Comment: I've edited what your written, just confirm it is correct

Comment: Plot the function and look at the part where $x \leq 3$. What do you see?

Comment: Also, it would be better to use another variable for the inverse function, for example $y$

Comment: yes it's correct. ok i'll try to plot it. later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know the inverse of $f$, you solve the equation $f(x)=y$. But\begin{align}f(x)=y&\iff2x^2-12x+7=y\\&\iff2x^2-12x+7-y=0\\&\iff x=3\pm\sqrt{\frac{y+11}2}.\end{align}But $x\in(-\infty,3]$. Therefore, if $y\ne-11$, you must take the solution $3-\sqrt{\frac{y+11}2}$; otherwise $x>3$.

Comment: i know this is years later, but x</3 is the domain of the function. so the domain of the function becomes the range of the inverse function. therefore the rule is that y</3 for the inverse function. so how do we know the domain of the inverse function is x</3? i mean it is probably not. but I'm just confused about the rule : x </3 for the inverse function. why is that rule true?

Comment: @ilovecupcakes Actually, the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $[-11,\infty)$. Which is natural, since this the range of $f$.

Comment: so then how come x can't be more than the value 3? because the domain of the inverse function is from -11 to infinity in the positive direction...

Comment: im confused....

Comment: @ilovecupcakes I must admit that I don't know what you are asking me. Do mind to try to be more clear?

Comment: What I am asking precisely is : 
the domain of the function becomes the range of the inverse function.
The range of the function becomes the domain of the inverse function.

The domain of the function is x</3
the range of the function is y>/-11

the domain of the inverse function is x>/-11
the range of the inverse function is y</3

so why does x have to be greater than 3 in the inverse function? If its domain is x>/-11 which includes 3 and values greater than 3?

Comment: @ilovecupcakes I don't now the meaning of “why does $x$ have to be greater than $3$ in the inverse function”. What is that $x$ and where did I claim that it has to be greater than $3$?

Comment: sorry, my bad. i meant why does x have to be less than 3 in the inverse function if it's domain is x>/-11? x>/-11 includes 3 and numbers greater than 3. here again, I'm sorry for the error I made.

Comment: you said that x cannot be > 3 in your answer. and I agreed with that previously. because the domain of the function is x</3. but then i thought, the domain of the inverse function is  x>/-11, and that includes the number 3 and values greater. so that's where my confusion stems from.

Comment: im confusing the hell out of you, aren't I?

Comment: i just realized why i'm wrong. nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

"Completing the square" produces

$$f(x) \ = \ 2x^2 - 12x + 7 \ = \ 2 \ · \ ( x^2 \ - \ 6x \ + \ 9 ) \ - \ 11 \ = \ 2 \ · \ ( x \ - \ 3)^2 \ - \ 11 \ \ , $$

so restricting the domain to $ \ x \ \le \ 3 \  $ uses only the "left half" of the parabola, which is the graph of a one-to-one function and so will permit the construction of an inverse function.  The function is not negative:  you are just finding the solution from the quadratic equation that use the "negative" square-root.  (The solution with the "positive" square-root corresponds to the "right half" of the parabola.)